# pgRouting CMAKE cannot find CGAL

Tags: pgrouting

I'm not able to install pgrouting on Centos 6.4 with Postgresql 9,3 and postgis 2.0.
I tried from the rpm, but I didn't found the repository.
I tried building from the source but I got the following error:

```
# cmake -DPOSTGRESQL_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgres -DPOSTGRESQL_PG_CONFIG:FILEPATH=/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config -L ..
```

[...]

```
    Boost  found.
Found Boost components:
   thread
-- CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR=CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
-- CGAL_LIBRARIES=CGAL_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
-- BOOST_THREAD_LIBRARIES=optimized;boost_thread-mt-shared;debug;boost_thread-mt-shared-debug
-- GMP_LIBRARIES=GMP_LIBRARIES-NOTFOUND
-- CGAL not found.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:294 (message):
   Please check your CGAL installation, or set correct path to CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR and CGAL_LIBRARIES.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I don't need CGAL, so How can I proceed without CGAL or How can I install it in order to proceed further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CGAL* is required for the *Driving Distance* function.

You can run cmake without it as seen at https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting

`cmake -DWITH_DD=OFF ..`

Answer (score 0):

`yum search cgal`

then you can install whatever you find it to be useful by:

`sudo yum install xxxxx`

For example:

`sudo yum install CGAL.x86_64 CGAL-devel.x86_64`

Good Luck !